# Microsoft Azure Speech to Text Java issue: ConnectionFailure when using proxy

Tags: java, azure, speech-to-text, azure-speech

I am trying to get the Microsoft Azure **Speech To Text** Java quickstart available at:
[Java Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/speech-to-text-from-microphone?tabs=dotnet%2Cx-android%2Clinux%2Candroid%2Cwindowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-java) to work as stated.

I haven't yet been able to do so.
On running the code, the following error is displayed on the Eclipse console:

```
Say something...
CANCELED: Reason=Error
CANCELED: ErrorCode=ConnectionFailure
CANCELED: ErrorDetails=Connection failed (no connection to the remote host). Internal error: 1. Error details: 11002. Please check network connection, firewall setting, and the region name used to create speech factory. SessionId: 56caf94e5a9b4c499e5c78b5bd659dcf
CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?
```

I have tried regenerating the **speechSubscriptionKey** in the Azure console for my Azure Speech resource.
I am using `centralindia` as the **serviceRegion** .

- I have a free trial subscription.
- JDK version: `1.8.0_231` for 64-bit.
- OS: Microsoft Windows 10
- IDE: Eclipse Luna

I am in a network that uses a proxy server. I tried after configuring the proxy settings as:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "<ProxyHost>");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "<ProxyPort>");
```

Still doesn't work. 
**P.S:** I have a working microphone attached to the system.

Comment: Please try `SpeechConfig.setProxy("proxyHost", "proxyPort", "", "")`

Comment: Yes! This works. The syntax is available at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechconfig.setproxy?view=azure-java-stable

Comment: Hi, I have update the solution of this question in the answer. Can you mark it as the answer to end this question? That may help others who meet the similar question. You can also post your own answer and mark it to end this question. If so, let me know and I will delete my answer.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Daud's comment.

```
 SpeechConfig.setProxy("proxyHost", "proxyPort", "", "")
```

More details can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechconfig.setproxy?view=azure-java-stable).